# Is it possible to have a date input in a w2ui toolbar

Tags: w2ui

I am wondering if there is any way one could place a date input control in a toolbar similar to the one used for date input on a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but it's quirky.

You will have to define the input field as a toolbar button:

```
{ type: 'html',   id: 'roles', html: '<input id="id_role">' },
```

and in the toolbar's onRefresh() event you will have to cast the input to the desired w2filed:

```
        onRefresh: function(event) {
            if(event.target == 'roles'){
                // w2field in toolbar must be initialized during refresh
                // see: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/886
                event.onComplete = function(ev){
                    $("#id_role").w2field('list', { items: roles });
                };
            }
        },
```

In my example I'm inserting a drop down list, but you can adjust it to your needs.

Please see https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/issues/886 for an "official" reply.